why does git update-ref also stage the files between old and new commits?
I've a script that refreshes the index to latest commit but git also stages the files changed between the old and new commits which I don't expect.
Steps are as following :
Fetch latest changes from remote repo
git fetch origin master 

Git references looks like the following now :
❯ git show-ref | grep -E "master$"
79ba3075fcf4263273dfd222cdd7773624c80913 refs/heads/master
688e154cf3bc04198b401789e75e4d496f7344b6 refs/remotes/gerrit/master
c87fb2b5bc576a23e9af600745210d7b9cab30d2 refs/remotes/origin/master

Update the local reference with the latest remote refernce.
git update-ref refs/heads/master refs/remotes/origin/master

Now the local reference is updated too which we expected
❯ git show-ref | grep -E "master$"
c87fb2b5bc576a23e9af600745210d7b9cab30d2 refs/heads/master
688e154cf3bc04198b401789e75e4d496f7344b6 refs/remotes/gerrit/master
c87fb2b5bc576a23e9af600745210d7b9cab30d2 refs/remotes/origin/master

Now I expected the git status to report that local branch is upto date with remote branch since the local reference is updated as of remote reference.
But I see that git also staged the files which were changed between the old and new commits.
git status  | wc -l         
3196

I don't understand why would that happen. My current branch is same "master".
I did not get any clue over the web or in the command manual. Any idea what could be the reason ?

Are you working on that branch? Well.... if that is the case then git status should be showing all the changes between index (which hasn't changed) and the new position of the branch (which you changed).... and then the changes between index and your working tree on top of that.

@eftshift0 Indeed, I was on the same branch as well.  Perhaps you are right because if follos these steps while being on a different branch and then if I switch to the master branch.  git status tells me local branch is up to date with remote branch. Which we expect.
My expectation while being on same branch , after updating the local index, git status would also tell the same thing that local branch is upto date with remote.  But that is not the case.

If you also would like to get the index to join the new position of the current local branch in a single shot then I think you would be better off by using git reset origin/master. That uses --mixed by default which reads: "Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.". So you would get the pointer of the current branch to the same commit as origin/master and you would also set the index over there in a single shot.

Just in case, I wonder why you think that update-ref would touch the index. And I say that because i your comment you say "...after updating the local index..."... where? I did not see a checkout/switch, or a reset.... or an add/mv/rm command anywhere so the index is not touched.... am I missing something? When you did the update-ref of a different local branch and then you ran git checkout/git switch to get yourself on it you did touch the index, that is the difference.

... and as my final 2 cents, given that you would also like to get the working tree to resemble the content of the remote branch (which is what you get when you do the git checkoutwhen you do the update-ref from a different branch), then I would like to point out that you should run git reset --hard instead (which moves the local branch pointer, adjusts the index and also the working tree)..... use with care as you would lose any uncommitted things you would have laying around the working tree/index.

I think the question deserves an answer, just in case.

Indeed git reset origin/master is the kind of behavior I expected that is I don't want the working tree to be updated but just index and reference updated.

I wonder why you think that update-ref would touch the index

Thanks that was misunderstanding my part. I meant local reference not the index.  I've fixed that in the question now.
You already have answered the question. If you could post the formal answer, I would be happily accept that.  Thank you.

The problem here is that you are assuming that you would end up with the working tree and the index looking exactly like the new position of the branch that you are working on and adjusting.
If you are working on branch-X and you adjust the reference of branch-Y, then when you run git checkout branch-Y git will move the pointer of HEAD to that branch, and make index look like the commit pointed to by branch-Y and adjust the working tree accordingly.
However, if you are on branch-Y and you move that branch to a different commit (without messing with the index and the working tree, just like what you would expect update-ref to do), git would have to consider (as it always does) the differences between index and the commit that the branch is now pointing to (which can be A LOT, because the index will look much like the previous commit the branch was pointing to) and the differences between index and the working tree.... and all of that simply because update-ref does not mess up with index or the working tree.
If you wanted to get the working tree and the index to also resemble the content of the new position of the branch, you should consider using git reset --hard instead to do the 3 things:

get the branch to point to the new position
get the index to resemble that commit
get the working tree to resemble that commit

Use with care as git reset --hard will get rid of any uncommitted changes that were laying around the index or the working tree.
